# how to append a smaller string in between a larger string in python?

Tags: python, string

I am new to python and i want to append a smaller string to a bigger string at a position defined by me. For example, have a string `aaccddee`. Now i want to append string `bb` to it at a position which would make it `aabbccddee`. How can I do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022827/how-to-insert-some-string-in-the-given-string-at-given-index-in-python

This should help explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice strings up as if they were lists, like this:

```
firststring = "aaccddee"
secondstring = "bb"
combinedstring = firststring[:2] + secondstring + firststring[2:]
print(combinedstring)
```

There is [excellent documentation on the interwebs](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html).

Answer (score 2):

String is immutable, you might need to do this:

```
strA = 'aaccddee'
strB = 'bb'
pos = 2
strC = strA[:pos]+strB+strA[pos:]  #  get aabbccddee
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this, but it's a tiny bit fiddlier than some other languages, as strings in python are immutable. This is quite an easy one to follow

First up, find out where in the string `c` starts at:

```
add_at = my_string.find("c")
```

Then, split the string there, and add your new part in

```
new_string = my_string[0:add_at] + "bb" + my_string[add_at:]
```

That takes the string up to the split point, then appends the new snippet, then the remainder of the string

Answer (score 1):

try these in a python shell:

```
string = "aaccddee"
string_to_append = "bb"
new_string = string[:2] + string_to_append + string[2:]
```

you can also use a more printf style like this:

```
string = "aaccddee"
string_to_append = "bb"
new_string = "%s%s%s" % ( string[:2], string_to_append, string[2:] )
```

Comment: sorry i did not mark the answer down...i do not even have permission to upvote or downvote...!

Comment: Thanks for the honesty @hnvasa. I feel like it was one of the other answerers, but have no real idea.

Answer (score 0):

Let say your string object is `s=aaccddee`. The you can do it as:

```
s = s[:2] + 'bb' + s[2:]
```