# Insert a string before a substring of a string

Tags: python, string

I want to insert some text before a substring in a string.

For example:

```
str = "thisissometextthatiwrote"
substr = "text"
inserttxt = "XX"
```

I want:

```
str = "thisissomeXXtextthatiwrote"
```

Assuming *substr* can only appear once in *str*, how can I achieve this result? Is there some simple way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24450558/1326943

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to insert some string in the given string at given index in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022827/how-to-insert-some-string-in-the-given-string-at-given-index-in-python)

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu it's not a dupe of that one, because that one doesn't ask how to find the index of substr

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
my_str = "thisissometextthatiwrote"
substr = "text"
inserttxt = "XX"

idx = my_str.index(substr)
my_str = my_str[:idx] + inserttxt + my_str[idx:]
```

ps: avoid using reserved words (i.e. `str` in your case) as variable names

Answer (score 18):

Why not use `replace`?

```
my_str = "thisissometextthatiwrote"
substr = "text"
inserttxt = "XX"

my_str.replace(substr, substr + inserttxt)
# 'thisissometextXXthatiwrote'
```

Comment: In Python .replace() returns a copy of string, so I guess it should be:


`new_str = my_str.replace(substr, substr + inserttxt)`

Comment: This is confusing it replaces `text` with `textXX`

Answer (score 10):

Use `str.split(substr)` to split str to `['thisissome', 'thatiwrote']`, since you want to insert some text **before** a substring, so we join them with "XXtext" (`(inserttxt+substr)`).

so the final solution should be:

```
>>>(inserttxt+substr).join(str.split(substr))
'thisissomeXXtextthatiwrote'
```

if you want to append some text **after** a substring, just replace with:

```
>>>(substr+appendtxt).join(str.split(substr))
'thisissometextXXthatiwrote'
```

Comment: could you add an explanation?

Comment: @Robert using `str.split(substr)` to split `str` to `['thisissome', 'thatiwrote']`, and then we join them with "XXtext" (`(inserttxt+substr)`).

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the question (were ´my_str´ is the variable), the right is:

```
(inserttxt+substr).join(**my_str**.split(substr))
```