# How to add commas at required positions in the given string in Python?

Tags: python, string

How to add commas at required positions in the given string in Python?
In my case, the positions are not fixed.

Example: My requirement is to add the commas after 5th, 8th, 11th, 13th in an `input string = "hello Python program"`

My expected output would be: `hello, Py,tho,n p,rogram`

Is there any simplest way to achieve this in Python?

Actually I need to apply a comma on 590 positions in my file record and then process it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert some string into given string at given index in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022827/insert-some-string-into-given-string-at-given-index-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add string in a certain position in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable in python, so if you're going to perform modifications on the string, it would be more efficient to convert the string to a list first. You can then call `str.join` on the string once you're done.

```
string = list("hello Python program") # somewhat counterintuitive a name

for i, j in enumerate([5, 8, 11, 13]):
     string.insert(i + j, ',')

print(''.join(string))
'hello, Py,tho,n ,program'
```

Comment: Dear cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, it works perfectly for me. Thanks for help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> string = "hello Python program"
>>> commas = [5, 8, 11, 13]
```

One way (probably the most efficient):

```
>>> ','.join(string[i:j] for i, j in zip([None] + commas, commas + [None]))
'hello, Py,tho,n ,program'
```

Another (for this one, `commas` should be a `set` for efficiency):

```
>>> ''.join(c + ',' * (i in commas) for i, c in enumerate(string, 1))
'hello, Py,tho,n ,program'
```

Another:

```
>>> a = list(string)
>>> for i in reversed(commas):
        a.insert(i, ',')
>>> ''.join(a)
'hello, Py,tho,n ,program'
```

Comment: I like your 2nd and 3rd options

Comment: Possibly, yes, but I am a fan of aesthetics as much as performance ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Hmm, I do like it for aesthetics as well. I think it's more straight-forward than our others. Going character by character or inserting backwards or adding an enumeration counter to the indexes all seem somewhat indirect.

Comment: Hi, facing some issue with output now. I am reading a file with is of 2199 length and trying to place commas at required positions. in an output I am getting like below, commas are coming into next line. This is happening for few records. 
Ex: 000XXXXXX,062,035,00,00 <=== First line   ,000C160YYYYY,086,047,00, <=== next line, Code is                      
  for line in file:
      string=list(line)   
      commas=[15,18,21,23,25]
      for i in reversed(commas):            
            string.insert(i, ',')            
        
      result=''.join(string)
      outfile.write(result)

Comment: @Sekhar Then your lines probably include the newline character at the end and you're putting a comma behind that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
def insertc(index,s,c):
    return s[:index]+c+s[index:]
s='hello Python program'
j=0
for i in [5,8,11,13]:
    s=insertc(i+j,s,',')
    j+=1
print(s)
```

Comment: Well it works now, but it was wrong before. Note that your answer is very similar to my answer, only more inefficient.