# How can quickly merge strings in Python

Tags: python

I have strings like this:

```
strA = "Today is hot. My dog love hot dog, milk, and candy."
strB = "hot dog and bread"
```

I hope the output string like:

```
"Today is hot. My dog love hot dog and bread, milk, and candy."
```

not

```
"Today is hot dog and bread. My dog love hot dog, milk, and candy."
```

I tried to use `str.find()`
but it's not suitable.

```py
if strA.find(strB) != -1:    
    x = strA.find(strB)
    listA = list(strA)
    listA.insert(x, strB)
    output = ''.join(listA)
```

Comment: What are the merging rules?

Comment: This may help
[Insert some string into given string at given index in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022827/insert-some-string-into-given-string-at-given-index-in-python)

Comment: @KlausD.  I update my question, thanks!  It want merging the most similar sentence.

Comment: @FurryBear, ok, what's the expected output for `"Today is hot. My dog love hot dog, milk. But my cat loves hot dog and fish"` ?

Comment: this problem is very similar to [sequence alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) in bioinformatics.  an aim there is to find the closest matching substring while allowing for mistakes.  you could then use this match to do your insertion/replacement of text

Comment: @SamMason it's very useful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a reverse lookup and return the best matched result.

```
strA = "Today is hot. My dog love hot dog, milk, and candy."
strB = "hot dog and bread"

def replace_method(string_a,string_b):
    s = string_b.split()
    for i in reversed(range(len(s)+1)):
        if " ".join(s[:i]) in string_a:
            return string_a.replace(" ".join(s[:i]),string_b)

print (replace_method(strA,strB))
```

Result:

```
Today is hot. My dog love hot dog and bread and cheese, milk, and candy.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strA = "My dog love hot dog, milk, and candy."
strB = "dog and bread"

strA = strA.replace('dog,',strB);
print(strA);
```

this is not a dynamic solution. but can work for this problem

Comment: sorry, my bad, i didn't notice that comma.

Comment: how about `strB = "hot dog and bread"` and `strA.replace("hot dog", strB)` ?