# How to add text within two string delimiters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to add some text within two delimiters in a string.

Previous string:

```
'ABC [123]'
```

New string needs to be like this:

```
'ABC [123 sometext]'
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `.replace(']', 'sometext]')`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022827/insert-some-string-into-given-string-at-given-index-in-python/4023434

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of these types of changes depend on prerequisite knowledge of string pattern.

In your case simple `str.replace` would do the trick.

```
varstr = 'ABC [123]';
varstr.replace(']',' sometext]');
```

You can profit a lot from [str doc](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp) and diving into [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp);

Answer (score 1):

*slightly* more versatile I'd say, without using `replace`:

```py
s = 'ABC [123]'
insert = 'sometext'
insert_after = '123'
delimiter = ' '

ix = s.index(insert_after)
if ix != -1:
    s = s[:ix+len(insert_after)] + delimiter + insert + s[ix+len(insert_after):]
    # or with an f-string:
    # s = f"{s[:ix+len(insert_after)]}{delimiter}{insert}{s[ix+len(insert_after):]}"

print(s)
# ABC [123 sometext]
```

If the insert patterns get more complex, I'd also suggest to take a look at `regex`. If the pattern is simple however, not using `regex` should be the more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are correct but if somehow you are trying to add a variable

```
variable_string = 'ABC [123]'
sometext = "The text you want to add"

variable_string = variable_string.replace("]", " " + sometext + "]")
print(variable_string)
```