# How to insert hyphens into a UUID string?

Tags: python, uuid

I want to create a function that adds a `-` on position 8, 12, 16, 20 of a  UUID string.

Example:

```
Original: 76684739331d422cb93e5057c112b637
New: 76684739-331d-422c-b93e-5057c112b637
```

I have no clue on how to position it on multiple positions in a string that wouldn't look like spaghetti code.

Comment: You could slice the string and `join` the parts with `'-'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert some string into given string at given index in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022827/insert-some-string-into-given-string-at-given-index-in-python)

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435169/how-do-i-append-one-string-to-another-in-python

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you are working with UUIDs.  There's a [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) for that that comes standard with Python:

```py
import uuid
s = '76684739331d422cb93e5057c112b637'
u = uuid.UUID(hex=s)
print(u)
```

```
76684739-331d-422c-b93e-5057c112b637
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex is another way, \S matches any non-whitespace character, number in {} is numbers of characters.

```
import re
​
new=re.sub(r'(\S{8})(\S{4})(\S{4})(\S{4})(.*)',r'\1-\2-\3-\4-\5',original)

print(new)

# 76684739-331d-422c-b93e-5057c112b637
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by progressively appending on a new string by slicing:

```py
original = "76684739331d422cb93e5057c112b637"
indices = [8, 12, 16, 20]
delimiter = "-"

new_string = ""
prev = 0
for index in indices:
    new_string += original[prev:index] + delimiter
    prev = index
new_string += original[prev:]

print(new_string)
# 76684739-331d-422c-b93e-5057c112b637
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the following arguments:

```py
delimiter = '-'
indexes = [8,12,16,20]
string = '76684739331d422cb93e5057c112b637'
```

You can use a `list comprehension` with `join`:

```py
idx = [0] + indexes + [len(string)]
delimiter.join([string[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)])
```

Output:

```
'76684739-331d-422c-b93e-5057c112b637'
```