# How would I insert a word into a string?

Tags: python

I have a string `https://www.exampleurl.com/`
How would I insert a word in the middle of a string so it could look like this: `https://www.subdomain.exampleulr.com/`

I know I can insert the word if I did this:

```
url = 'https://www.exampleurl.com/'
url[:12] + 'subdomain'
```

It prints me `https://www.subdomain`, but I can't figure out how to print the rest of the string dynamically so it would adjust to the subdomain that is being appended to the string.
My goal is for the end result to look like the following `https://www.subdomain.exampleurl.com/`

Comment: url += 'subdomain'

Comment: You forgot to add the second part: `url[:12] + 'subdomain.' + url[12:]`

Comment: The same way you extracted the first part: `url[:12] + 'subdomain' + url[12:]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert some string into given string at given index in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022827/insert-some-string-into-given-string-at-given-index-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
url = 'https://www.exampleurl.com/'
content = url.split("www.")

url = content[0] + "www." + "subdomain." + content[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
url = 'https://www.exampleurl.com/'
text = url.split(".")

url =  text[0] + '.subdomain.' + text[1] + '.' + text[2]
```

Final output : `https://www.subdomain.exampleurl.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Better split on the first `.`:

```
l = url.split('.', 1)
l[0] + '.subdomain.' + l[1]

## OR if subdomain is a variable:
f'{l[0]}.{subdomain}.{l[1]}'
```

output: `'https://www.subdomain.exampleurl.com/'`

Answer (score 0):

Using replace (once)

```
url = 'https://www.exampleurl.com/'
url = url.replace(".", ".subdomain.", 1)   # only replaces first "." to 
                                           # get desured result
```