# Python Inserting a string

Tags: python

I need to insert a string (character by character) into another string at every 3rd position
For example:- string_1:-wwwaabkccgkll
String_2:- toadhp
Now I need to insert string2 char by char into string1 at every third position
So the output must be wwtaaobkaccdgkhllp
Need in Python.. even Java is ok

So i tried this

```
Test_str="hiimdumbiknow"
challenge="toadh"
new_st=challenge [k]
Last=list(test_str)
K=0
For i in range(Len(test_str)):
    if(i%3==0):
        last.insert(i,new_st)
    K+=1
```

and the output i get
thitimtdutmbtiknow

Comment: Your code gives me more questions than it answers. What is `k`? Why are `For` and `Len` in title-case? What is `K` (upper-case this time) for?

Comment: Oh shoot... sorry i forgot to remove it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert some string into given string at given index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022827/insert-some-string-into-given-string-at-given-index)

Answer (score 1):

You can split `test_str` into sub-strings to length 2, and then iterate merging them with `challenge`:

```
def concat3(test_str, challenge):
    chunks = [test_str[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(test_str),2)]
    result = []
    i = j  = 0
    while i<len(chunks) or j<len(challenge):
        if i<len(chunks):
            result.append(chunks[i])
            i += 1
        if j<len(challenge):
            result.append(challenge[j])
            j += 1
    return ''.join(result)

test_str  = "hiimdumbiknow"
challenge = "toadh"

print(concat3(test_str, challenge))
# hitimoduambdikhnow
```

This method works even if the lengths of `test_str` and `challenge` are mismatching. (The remaining characters in the longest string will be appended at the end.)

Answer (score 0):

You can split `Test_str` in to groups of two letters and then re-join with each letter from `challenge` in between as follows;

```
import itertools
print(''.join(f'{two}{letter}' for two, letter in itertools.zip_longest([Test_str[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(Test_str),2)], challenge, fillvalue='')))
```

Output:

```
hitimoduambdikhnow
```

*edited to split in to groups of two rather than three as originally posted

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, make an iter above the second string and iterate over the first one and select which character should be part of the final string according the position

```
def add3(s1, s2):
    def n():
        try:
            k = iter(s2)
            for i,j in enumerate(s1):
                yield (j if (i==0 or (i+1)%3) else next(k))
        except:
            try:
                yield s1[i+1:]
            except:
                pass 
    return ''.join(n())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def insertstring(test_str,challenge):
    result = ''
    x = [x for x in test_str]
    y = [y for y in challenge]
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if i % 2 != 0 or i == 0:
            result += x[i]
        else:
            if j < 5:
                result += y[j]
                result += x[i]
                j += 1
    get_last_element = x[-1]
    return result + get_last_element


print(insertstring(test_str,challenge))

#output: hitimoduambdikhnow
```