# How to insert every nth charts in string? PYTHON

Tags: python, string, insert

I have a code, but I don't really know python, so I have a problem. I know that the insert isn't right for strings but I don't know how can I insert?

```
original_string = input("What's yout sentence?")
add_character = input("What char do you want to add?")
slice = int(input("What's the step?"))

for i in original_string[::slice]:
    original_string.insert(add_character)

print("The string after inserting characters: " + str(original_string))
```

So I need help, how can I rewrite this? That's the homework for university and we haven't studied def so I can't use it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022827/insert-some-string-into-given-string-at-given-index This will be helpful I think

Comment: Could you please post an example of the input and the expected output?

Comment: Hi, to me the easiest way would be like this ..

original_string = original_string[:slice] + add_character + original_string[slice:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
original_string = input("What's yout sentence?")
add_character = input("What char do you want to add?")
slice = int(input("What's the step?"))

new_string = ""

for index, letter in enumerate(original_string):
    if index % slice == 0 and index != 0:
        new_string += add_character + letter
    else:
        new_string += letter

print("The string after inserting characters: " + str(new_string))
```

Explanation: Strings are immutable so we'll have to create a new string to append to. So loop through the original string, take each letter and its index. If the index is a multiple of the slice, then add the character in add_character variable along with the letter, otherwise only append the letter. This will add the character at every multiple of the slice. I believe this is what the code was trying to achieve atleast, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: sorry, forgot to add. the index != 0 is to avoid appending the character at the start of the string

Answer (score 0):

Also I try to use .join, but now it prints original string, how can I print the string with joined chars?

```
    original_string = input("What's yout sentence?")
    add_character = input("What char do you want to add?")
    slice = int(input("What's the step?"))
    
    for i in original_string[::slice]:
        original_string.join(add_character)
    

print("The string after inserting characters: " + str(original_string))
```